# How did scientists manage to measure the charge of electron so precisely?

Tags: electrons, charge

According to the latest CODATA reports the charge of electron is known very precisely $\approx 1.6021765314 \times 10^{-19}$. My question is: How is this charge determined with such high precision? What experiments are done to this end? When I googled I only found some information about the classical oil drop experiment, but I'm not convinced it can yield such precise results.

Comment: like Millikan did. Look for Lienneman , PHY 192 in this page [Faculty Teaching Assignments](http://www.pa.msu.edu/courses/teaching/teaching-assignments_2012.html)

Comment: Interesting note: Found in one of Millikans students (student named Fletcher) letters opened post death, he(Fletcher) said he had the idea and used oil first. Fletcher assumed he would be included in the paper as he was in previous papers but was omitted by Millikan.

Comment: An up-vote for the question. I would appreciate a nice, succinct explanation as to how the charge of the electron was measured to about 10 significant digits or more. All of the commonly used lab measuring instruments I have (e.g., voltmeters, lock-in amps, ohmmeters, digital weight scale, etc.) only give a resolution of about 4 or 5 significant digits. So how does one go about measuring something like the charge of an electron to 10 or more significant digits?

Answer (score 3):

This is too long for a comment. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge)

> In the most recent CODATA adjustments, the elementary charge is not an
> independently defined quantity. Instead, a value is derived from the
> relation
>
> $$e^2 = \frac{2h \alpha}{\mu_0 c} = 2h \alpha \epsilon_0 c$$
>
> where $h$ is the Planck constant, $α$ is the fine structure constant,
> $μ_0$ is the magnetic constant, $ε_0$ is the electric constant and $c$
> is the speed of light. The uncertainty in the value of $e$ is
> currently determined entirely by the uncertainty in the Planck
> constant.
>
> The most precise values of the Planck constant come from watt balance
> experiments, which are currently used to measure the product
> $K_j^2R_K$. The most precise values of the fine structure constant
> come from comparisons of the measured and calculated value of the
> gyromagnetic ratio of the electron.

The article has links, but they are pay walled.